# Alternatives to deploying smart contract with high gas fees?

Tags: contract-deployment, gas, truffle-contract

I have a dApp contract that costs ~ 80 USD to deploy at 46 gwei. I just have 10 USD to do this.

Is there any way I can do this in less? I don't mind deploying it to a network other than ETH Mainnet.

Comment: you can reduce the gas price, to 10gwei when deploying, it might put your transaction in the pending for sometime but that might be your only option.

Comment: transactions on Polygon are basically for free

Comment: to deploy on the Main Net wait for Satruday or Sunday morning , NY time

Answer (score 1):

You can also deploy the contract on matic(polygon) network which uses much lower fee than even BSC!

This link tells you how to add matic network to your metamask wallet:
https://docs.matic.network/docs/develop/metamask/config-matic/

Also I should note that matic network uses polygon(matic) as fee. (You can find about this token in [coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/polygon/) or [coingecko](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/polygon))

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test it, use an ethereum testnet. Here are some links:

**Testnets:** https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/networks/#testnets

**Testnet Faucets:** https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/networks/#testnet-faucets
(Get fake testnet eth)

You will just have to configure your metamask to be on one of these testnets.

**You can also try Binance Smart Chain Mainnet**, which has much lower fees; here is a link for that: https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/connecting-metamask-to-binance-smart-chain

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I have already tested it on Rinkeby. Regarding the BSC, does it use ETH, or will I have to edit my whole dApp to use Binance Coin ?

Comment: It uses BNB (BEP20) - but you will most likely not have to change too much, if anything in the code. BSC also uses EVM and Solidity. So maybe test on the BSC Testnet just to make sure first.